# Issue loading View Controller from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the past my app has had only 1 main view controller (`MainViewController`) and a login view controller (`LoginViewController`) but now I am moving to a Tab Bar Controller.

Before I was able to do a simple check `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController` for the existence of a username and password in the key chain. If a username and password was not present I used a segue to pop up a modal login view controller.

With the new setup of using a Tab Bar Controller I still only have 1 view controller (`MainViewController`) which is the root view controller (as of now) and I am trying to do the same thing where it pops up modal of the login screen.

Now when I call the segue in the `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadLoginView" sender:nil];`

I am getting this error:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x1757cd80> on <UITabBarController: 0x17571e50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

But if I associate a button to a method that loads the `LoginViewController` by way of a segue it works fine. I am doing that in the `MainViewController` like this:

```
-(void)loadLogin
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadLoginView" sender:nil];
}
```

I can see from the error message that when I try to perform the segue from the `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController` it's trying to load the `LoginViewController` from `UITabBarController`.

Why can I not load the `LoginViewController` from the `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`?

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `-viewDidLoad` is getting called before your view controller stack is added to the window. Two things you could try are:

Delaying until the next time through the run loop (this should give the view controllers time to get in place) `[self performSelector:@selector(loadLogin) withObject:self afterDelay:0];`. This method won't allow you to call a method with two arguments directly

You could use `-presentViewController: animated: completion:`. This will cause your login controller to slide in from the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the help - [self performSelector:@selector(loadLogin) withObject:self afterDelay:0] works but I am getting this warring - Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x1d0192c0>. If I make the delay 1 I do not get the warring but it's rather slow like that.

Comment: What if you use a delay of 0.1? Not sure where the unbalanced call is coming from.

Comment: That worked with 0.1. Thanks! Also, just an FYI. I tried doing it with -presentViewController: animated: completion: and I got the same original error message. THanks Again